# Detecting white text on HTML file

Tags: python, html

I have HTML file like this:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <style>
            .secret {
                background-color: black;
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <p>This text is VISIBLE</p>
        <p id="hidden-1" style="color: white;">This text is hidden (white text background)</p>
        <p id="hidden-2" class="secret">This text is hidden (black text/background)</p>
    </BODY>
<HTML>
```

I want to write a small Python application that get HTML file as an input and detects the HTML element that makes this trick. In the case above, the output should be "hidden-1" + "hidden-2".

Additional to the example above, there are many more options to hide text in HTML. I'm looking for a solution that has the highest rate of success.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Voted as too broad. I'm sure its possible but it isn't a simple problem that you'll get an answer for here. Start by looking for a python library that can parse css and html.

Comment: Too broad? I don't think so. This is a specific problem and I sure that it has multiple solutions. I looked in old stackoverflow threads and didn't found a thread about it. I think that it's a good time to start one.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Your question is akin to saying "how do I build a calculator in python?", yes it's a specific problem but the answer to that question is way too board to be answered in a simple Q&A format. You need to break down your problem more. Eg. "How do I read css with python".

Answer (score 1):

A general solution could be to use `bs4` to strip all the ids / text from the html. Then use `imgkit` to convert the .html to .png, and read the visible text from it with an OCR such as `pytesseract`, then do a diff to find the "hidden" text.